# Load Image from My.Resources to a Picturebox (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, picturebox, my.resources

I'm having trouble loading an image from My.Resources. I have already tried a no. of codes like....:

1. `PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.Online_lime_icon;` And
2. `PictureBox1.Image = CType(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Online_lime_icon"), Image)`

but it would still return:

```
Picturebox1.Image = Nothing
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to convert it `ToBitMap()`

```
 PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.Online_lime_icon.ToBitmap()
```

EDIT:

@user1615710 : My.Resources.Online_lime_icon doesn't have .ToBitmap. It only has .ToString.

That means you've `String` resource and I think it represents `fileName` with or without absolute path.

Try to print/show the content of `My.Resources.Online_lime_icon`

```
 Debug.Print(My.Resources.Online_lime_icon) 'or
 MsgBox(My.Resources.Online_lime_icon)
```

If it is *real* path then load the image via,

```
 PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(My.Resources.Online_lime_icon)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but `My.Resources.Online_lime_icon` doesn't have `.ToBitmap`. It only has `.ToString`.

Comment: Is it a file path or a stream?

Comment: @AVD I used messagebox to check what was the `.ToString` was all about and it turns out it just says the type of the object: it's output was "System.Drawing.Bitmap"  @Cole Johnson It's a bitmap I imported to the resources.

Comment: This worked for me: `ImageBox1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.my_image` . My image box was of type UI.ImageBox.